# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 Custom Proxy Fail and 4.7.1 works

Tags: wso2-esb

i have a custom proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.7 works correct.
But, when i copy to ESB 4.8.1 it's fail.

This is te code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ExpertWS"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">    <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://1.33.33.103:8080/erpws/logistica/master/ume/{pEmpresa}"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>    </target>    <description/> </proxy>
```

Any idea??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a http endpoint, properties names must start with "uri.var" : uri.var.pEmpresa and a value must be set

see https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/HTTP+Endpoint

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel, but it has to be another thing.
The two version unzziped in same server.

I tried multiple options and i always recive the same response in 4.8.1.
Status: 400 Petición incorrecta

In 4.7.0, is unzipped in same server, and works.